# Rokhlin lemma need not hold for arbitrary sequence

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I'm solving exercises of the book 'Ergodic throry with a view towards number theory' by my own, and I am too confused about the follwing exercise of the section 2.9, number 3.

---

### Show that the Kakutani-Rokhlin lemma dose not hold for arbitrary sequences of iterates of the map $T$. Specifically, show that for an ergodic measure-preserving system $(X, \mathcal{B},\mu, T)$, sequence $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ of distinct integers, and $\epsilon>0$ it is not always possible to find a measurable set $A$ with the properties that $T^{a_1}(A),…,T^{a_n}(A)$are disjoint and $\mu(\cup^n_{i=1} T^{a_i}(A)>1-\epsilon)$

First I'm confused about whether I can show in general that the set having the required property does not exist or I may suggest only a counterexample.

Second, I suppose I may suggest a counterexample, so for an invertible system we may consider the irrational rotation with an irrational $\alpha$. At first this example seemed useful because we can take an $n$ such that $n\alpha<\epsilon$, so we may get the sets closer to make them intersect, disproving the disjointness of the sets. But I cannot use the fact that the set $A$ has a positive measure, which seems to be related with the regularity of the Lebesgue measure on the circle, but to use open set I have to give up the disjointness condition and to use the compact set I cannot make use of the disjointness condition. How should I proceed here?

Any idea about this problem would be appreciated. I have been looking for all the references mentioned in the book, but never seen any proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment and is not a complete answer. (Also, I think the $\epsilon$ in the question should be replaced with a $1-\epsilon$. This makes more sense).

First, you are supposed to find a counterexample. Namely, find an ergodic system $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$, distinct integers $a_1,\dots,a_n$, and an $\epsilon > 0$ so that for any $A \in \mathcal{B}$ with $T^{a_1}(A),\dots,T^{a_n}(A)$ pairwise disjoint, we have $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^n T^{a_i}(A)) \le \epsilon$. You couldn't possibly prove that always such an $A$ does not exist since $a_1,\dots,a_n$ could be $1,\dots,n$ in which case there always exists an $A$, by the Kakutani-Rokhlin Lemma.

Second, I like the irrational rotation example. The positivity of the measure of $A$ will help us out via the Lebesgue Density Theorem (this book mentions that theorem a lot). I just tried typing up a proof but ran into some technical issues. I think the idea is roughly as follows. If we take $m \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\alpha m$ is close to an integer, then for the image under $T^m$ of an interval to be disjoint from itself, the interval needs to be pretty small. And then maybe this will prevent the measure of $A\cup T^m A$ from being more than $1-\epsilon$. The reason I can't make this directly into a proof is that $A$ can be a union of these small intervals - but maybe we would need too many intervals...

Comment: I think you are right that $1-\epsilon$ makes more sense, so I've edited it.(Maybe the author have committed a mistake) Also, thank you for noting that I really need to find a counterexample. Well, that seems now clear. But we're in the trouble in order to make use of the irrational rotation example. This is because if we choose any integer $m$, then we can set $\beta=\alpha m$ so that $R_{\beta}=R_{\alpha m}$ is again an irrational rotation. Thus in this case we can apply the Kakutani-Rohklin Lemma to the system $(X,\mathcal{b},\mu,R_{\beta})$ and the sequence {0, 1}.

Comment: @Jassenhaus ah, good observation. I wonder whether the irrational rotation can produce a counterexample (I guess with $n > 2$)

Comment: Yes, thus for this example we should try at least a triple pair $a_1, a_2, a_3$. Above argument can be equally applied to the case of $(\mathcal{T}^2,\mathcal{B}, \mu, R_{\alpha}^2)$. This is not ergodic but it it still aperiodic. Other invertible example is integer matrix multiplication on the torus, but it is mixing so I think it could not be a counterexample because of having to strong condition. Well, anyway the irrational rotation seems easier so I chose it, but with the triple it seems I cannot proceed further.

Comment: What about $X = \{x_1,x_2\}, \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{P}(X), \mu(x_i) = \frac{1}{2}$, and $Tx_1 = x_2, Tx_2 = x_1$. This an ergodic invertible measure preserving system, and $a_1 = 0, a_2 = 2$ with $\epsilon = .1$ (for example) will be a counterexample.

Comment: Oh, sorry for omitting the non-atomic hypothesis, which is contained in the Rohklin lemma. The author also omitted it, though.

Comment: @Jassenhaus My bad. I'm starting to think the irrational rotation won't produce a counterexample...

Comment: @Jassenhaus What's an example of a system where $T$ is ergodic but not $T^2$?

Comment: Umm...well that is mentioned in the exercise 2.5.6 'Total ergodicity' and I considered it while discussing this. But I've also found from discussing with you that we really have to deal with a triple. For, aperiodicity also ensures to use the Rohklin lemma, namely for any integer $n$ having $\mu({x:T^n (x)=x})=0$. This is problematic since any iterates of $T$ is again aperiodic, so....